# Prevent package manager recreating files in /etc/fonts/conf.d/

Tags: apt, fonts, etc

I use a bitmap font for my terminal windows. In order for this to work, I need to enable bitmap fonts. In `/etc/fonts/conf.d/` there's a symlink called `70-no-bitmaps.conf` to the matching configuration file in `/etc/fonts/conf.avail/`. I delete this symlink and create one for the matching `80-yes-bitmaps.conf`. This works.

(I also have the following in my ~/.fonts/fonts.conf file to suppress the hideous bitmap fonts that claim to be Helvetica and mess up web-pages:

```
<rejectfont>
    <glob>/usr/share/fonts/X11/*</glob>
</rejectfont>
```

This is fine for me because I only really use a single bitmap font lives in my home directory anyway.)

Unfortunately, every month or two, the package manager recreates the symlink, and when I have both files the `no` one takes precedence and disables bitmap fonts. What is the correct way to fix this so that it won't break again every time the package updates? I could replace the symlink with a dummy empty file, but this seems nasty and will leave the directory looking confusing - with both `yes-bitmaps` and `no-bitmaps` files, it won't be clear which is in effect until you look inside the files. Is there a better way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I've enabled bitmaps too (mainly for courier and unifont). Try

```
sudo touch /etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf
sudo chattr +i /etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf
```

This should set the immutable bit on a BLANK file in the place of the one that disables bitmap fonts, so that it can not be replaced or edited (even by root).

To allow changing the file again, just do

`sudo chattr -i /etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf`

I hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: I *think* the chattr is unnecessary. I think creating the blank file alone would do it. I haven't tested it out, but I think apt won't mess with configuration files you've edited. The problem here is that deleting the configuration file isn't considered an edit to be preserved.

Comment: If that is true, you could just make a blank file called '70-no-bitmaps.conf' by running the `touch` command.

Comment: Yes. That's what I said in the question. "I could replace the symlink with a dummy empty file", but I was hopeful there might be a better way without the drawbacks I described.

Comment: You could make a file called '70-yes-bitmaps-are-enabled-despite-the-other-conf-file.conf' and leave it blank or something.